# How to handle return types with multiple fields

Tags: ocaml, lablgtk

I am calling a method "get_text" on GText.buffer detailed here http://oandrieu.nerim.net/ocaml/lablgtk/doc/GText.buffer.html

```
let text = textView#buffer#get_text in
```

However as get_text returns multiple values, when I try to use my variable "text" as a string, for example

```
textView2#buffer#set_text text;
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: This expression has type
     ?start:GText.iter ->
     ?stop:GText.iter -> ?slice:bool -> ?visible:bool -> unit -> string
   but an expression was expected of type string
```

How can I access the string being returned by the method? In general, how can I separate the multiple values returned by a method so I can access and use them individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked up your link to lablgtk - it looks like you are missing the ():

```
let text = textView#buffer#get_text () in ...
```

The problem with this kind of error is that you are using a (curried) function where a string is required, and the message about the type error sounds kind of "long winded" and not to the point.

Comment: But it is exactly to the point. The value is not a string but a function taking a number of optional arguments followed by () returning a string. It's not ocamls fault the function has so many optional arguments, is it?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I thought exactly to the point would be "if you put the () then it will do what you want" ;-) Sounds like a feature request :-)